# How to change the volume of playback in MediaListPlayer with LibVLC?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vlc, libvlc

I'm using a `MediaListPlayer` instance to execute a playlist. On a standard `MediaPlayer` instance you can use `MediaPlayer.audio_set_volume(newVolume)`, but when I try to use the same method(`audio_set_volume(newVolume)`) on a `MediaListPLayer` instance, I get an error.:
`AtributeError: 'MediaListPLayer' object has no attribute 'audio_set_volume'`. What is the replacement of that method for the `MediaListPlayer`?

This is the code:

```
from vlc import Instance

playlist = ['/home/user/Music/01 Signs.mp3','/home/user/Music/2U.mp3']
player = Instance()
mediaListPlayer = player.media_list_player_new()
mediaList = player.media_list_new()
for element in playlist:
    mediaList.add_media(player.media_new(element))
mediaListPlayer.set_media_list(mediaList)
mediaListPlayer.play()
mediaListPlayer.audio_set_volume(80)
```

Comment: Looks like an oversight. I can't find a method to either change the current volume or re-set the default volume. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two years later was wondering the same thing. So here is a solution that worked for me:

```
import vlc

inst = vlc.Instance()
player = inst.media_list_player_new()
media_list = inst.media_list_new(["example.mp3"])
player.set_media_list(media_list)
player.play()

player.get_media_player().audio_set_volume(50)
```

MediaListPlayer.get_media_player() returns the MediaPlayer that can be used to control the volume of the MediaListPlayer during playback.

Comment: It's been a long time for sure, I ended up going with `ffmpeg` because the requisites changed, but great to know that there's a better way to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, it does look like an oversight.
However, I have managed to set the initial volume by hacking a sub_player but once it is set and you invoke the list player, I haven't found a way of adjusting it after that.

```
import vlc
import time
playlist=['/home/rolf/vp1.mp3','/home/rolf/vp.mp3']
inst = vlc.Instance()
sub_player = inst.media_player_new()
player = inst.media_list_player_new()
mediaList = inst.media_list_new(playlist)
player.set_media_list(mediaList)
volume = 60
sub_player.audio_set_volume(volume)
sub_player.play()
playing = set([1,2,3,4])
player.play()
while player.get_state() in playing:
    time.sleep(1)
```

I have posted a question on videolan ,https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=139505 so someone with a greater knowledge of these things might provide a better solution. If I get an answer, I'll post it here.

Comment: Okay, I'll wait. Thank you! I find it a little strange that the List Player doesn't​ have a volume changer. Can you give the link to your question there?